# Why does my table appear to be clearing vertical space within a cell?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a site in development here:

http://63.144.105.101/perfect-card-creator-step-3

(This page won't display everything unless you start from Page 1), but the elements are still showing their problem).

I want the section where you choose the type of credit card (Visa, MasterCard, etc.) to be up higher, lined up with the preview of the credit card. These are tables nested within tables, pulled from an old site. Everything is working as it should except for this unusual stacking behavior. I've tried adjusting the styles but to no avail. Need another pair of eyes on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: baseline;` seems to be the problem.  Change it to `vertical-align: top` and you're good.

The offending line is in `wp-content/themes/perfectplastic/style.css`, and is in the first few lines.

Since you probably don't want to break everything else, just add a class to the table you need and define `vertical-align` for that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried doing an override of "the reset" but must not have included enough of the offending elements.